# What is a kernel image? Why is it mandatory in Embedded?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, yocto

Now I'm working in a Yocto project. So, I heard this word called "image". What is that and why do we need that, and how does it take place in Embedded Projects?

Comment: Image is what would be placed on the storage in order to boot from.

Answer (score 7):

There are more things named `images` when it comes to the embedded world in general, and the [Yocto Project](https://yoctoproject.org) specifically.

First, there are `kernel images`, as you named in the post title. This is a binary form of the operating system core, nicknamed the `kernel`, that a bootloader can use to start the OS. In a YP context, this will almost always be a Linux kernel. The expression `image` there literally means one file that is the executable form of the Linux kernel. the same wording is used by the Linux Kernel devs too, by the way.

Secondly, there are `Operating System images`. Now those are a little bit specific to the embedded world, as you usually do not run an interactive installation of, say, Ubuntu, Debian or such, but prepare everything to be copied onto the target device in one go. This prepared form is also called `image`, as explained by Gino in the first answer.

Those OS images are not exactly mandatory: you can totally run an embedded system off a standard Linux distribution - given sufficient hardware support. Reversely, you can also run a desktop computer or even a cloud server on an image, and many people do this for a variety of reasons.

> In a nutshell, the main purpose of the Yocto Project technology is to produce these images.

Thirdly, for mostly smaller, non-Linuxy embedded systems, the term `image` often refers to the binary blob that the toolchain outputs. While the technical details are vastly different, it is probably sufficient to just think of it as "the second meaning, but without Linux" to get the mindset started.

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in the [Yocto Software Overview](https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-overview/) documentation:

> **Image**: A binary form of a Linux distribution (operating system)
>   intended to be loaded onto a device.

There is a more detailed explanation on the "images" produced by the build system in the [Yocto Project Overview and Concepts Manual > Images](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6.2/overview-manual/overview-manual.html#images-dev-environment) section:

> The images produced by the build system are compressed forms of the
>   root filesystem and are ready to boot on a target device.